# No tests running when running `anchor test`

Tags: anchor-test

I cloned my anchor repo but after installing the modules and building, testing the program results in 0 of the test cases running.

Here are the logs

```
Found a 'test' script in the Anchor.toml. Running it as a test suite!

Running test suite: "/home/jimii/Documents/crew/nft/Anchor.toml"

yarn run v1.22.19
$ /home/jimii/Documents/crew/nft/node_modules/.bin/ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 'tests/**/*.ts'


  0 passing (0ms)

Done in 0.52s.
Error: No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

The `anchor test` command fails but it swallows the error message.

You can run the test command manually to see why it's failing.

Look in `Anchor.toml` for the `test` command in the `[scripts]` section and run the command manually

```
yarn run ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 tests/**/*.ts
```

For example, the issue might be that `yarn` is not installed or you have an outdated version of Node.js (v20 or higher is recommended).

Comment: I tried running this but still got the same response. No tests are being run.

```ts
yarn run ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 tests/**/*.ts
yarn run v1.22.19
$ /home/jimii/Documents/crew/nft/node_modules/.bin/ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 tests/admin-test.ts tests/config.ts tests/loan-test.ts tests/rent/buy-test.ts tests/rent/durability.ts tests/rent/normal.ts tests/rent-test.ts tests/rent/trial.ts tests/sdktest.ts tests/streammoney-nft_old.ts tests/streammoney-nft.ts


  0 passing (1ms)

Done in 1.08s.
```